# What does "I gets mine" mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

In the last episode of "Curb Your Enthusiasm" there was this dialogue between Larry and Leon (black guy who uses a lot of street slang):

> Larry: You think I'd go out with a guy wearing a green wife-beater? Look at you. This sh*t on your head.
>
> Leon: Are you kidding me?
>
> Larry: What the hell is that?
>
> Leon: Oh, I gets mine, Larry. I f*king gets mine. You know I gets mine too.

What does "I gets mine" mean?

Comment: I mean, without watching the movie, it'll be hard for people to reply, for example, I just search google and find that it is a TV series movie show on HBO.

Comment: @StackUnderblow: I did watch a few episodes years ago (I was quite amused, as I recall), but I don't even remember a black guy called Leon. Nevertheless, I'd be pretty sure I've understood the last line. Not the earlier bit about "this shit on your head", obviously, because that's something visual that we can't see here. Perhaps he has a weird hairstyle - filthy dreadlocks or something.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Larry is referring to Leon's headgear (a do-rag).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently Leon is wearing a bandana, so that's what Larry means by *this shit on your head*. And *wife-beater* means a sleeveless singlet/vest (I think it usually means a dark blue one; I don't know if it's relevant that this one is green). Larry clearly thinks Leon doesn't look attractive.

Leon says *gets* rather than *get* just because it's "cool" to be ungrammatical. When he says *mine* he means *my oats* (his character might well not know of that the missing word). Basically, he's saying that he [gets his oats](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+oats) (he gets plenty of sex), so Larry shouldn't assume his appearance is off-putting to women.

Comment: Excellent explanation +1 :-D

Comment: Very well could be. Clothing details are irrelevant here I think, but Leon was wearing sleeveless green undershirt and bandana.

Comment: @serg: I think those details are relevant. Leon only says what he does to *prove* that he "looks good", after Larry says he looks a mess (implying women wouldn't be interested in him).

Comment: Point of interest: in NYC, if you said "Joe is wearing a wifebeater, what color shirt is Joe wearing?" most everyone would reply "white!".